# c# parameterized query not recognized

Tags: c#, sap-ase, parameterized-query

I have a query that is expected to return a few rows but is not returning any results in code. I have some value from an arraylist that I'm wrapping around single quotes and comma to be use in the 'in' operator.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
AseCommand cmd = new AseCommand("select * from Customer where ID in (@parmCustId)", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parmCustId", string.Join(",", arrList.Cast<string>().Select(x => string.Format("'{0}'", x))));
using (AseDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   if (dr.HasRows)
   {
      //do something
   }
}
```

Comment: You can't use IN like that

Comment: Note that the accepted answer to the duplicate is not necessarily the best. Look at all of the answers ans see which is best for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's really stupid what you have to do in this situation. You have to add a parameter for each value in the `IN` list.

So your query would end up something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE ID in (@parmCustId1, @parmCustId2, @parmCustId3 ... @parmCustId<N>)
```

Then your code would look something like this:

```
var query = "select * from Customer where ID in (@parmCustId)";
using (AseCommand cmd = new AseCommand("", conn))
{
    var replacement = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < arrList.Length; i++)
    {
        var id = arrList[i];
        var p = "@parmCustId" + i.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p, id);
        replacement += p;
        if (i != arrList.Length - 1)
        {
            replacement += ",";
        }
    }

    cmd.CommandText = query.Replace("@parmCustId", replacement);
    using (AseDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

There's also some libraries that will support this. For example, [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), written by the folks here at StackOverflow, will support this with ease. It's also a super fast and efficient object relational mapper (ORM) that can make some of the DataReader logic simpler if you're putting into an object. You can get it on NuGet.

Comment: It's not stupid: if databases dug into the parameter values passed and broke out/parsed them as if they were sql then they wouldn't offer any protection against injection attacks! :/ kudos for your example of adding N number of parameters and then adding a value for each though

Comment: Eh.. You're correct. Poor choice of words, but you get what I'm saying. Inconvenient would be more accurate.

Comment: I agree, though anyone who puts sql into a string in a Hutton click handler is arranging the "rod of inconvenience" for their own back :) . Entity framework et al exist for a good reason,. No one should be writing mundane sqls like this, in their code any more

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you wanted to run:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN(1,2,3,4)
```

Here's what you actually ran:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN ('1,2,3,4')
```

If you want to parameterise an IN, you'll have to put N number of parameters in, and give a value to each:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4)

//c# code here to populate 4 named parameters with an id each
```